# Getting jQuery and Bootstrap 4 JS working with Webpack and Middleman

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, webpack-2, middleman

Trying to get jQuery loaded up on my Webpack Config using Middleman.

I'm trying to use:

- Middleman 4.2.1
- Bootstrap 4 Beta
- jQuery 3

I have Bootstrap's CSS loading but now having problems trying to load jQuery along with Bootstrap's JS components.

Unsure if I'm doing things correctly with the `ProviderPlugin`

I've saved all the dependencies using `--save-dev` option.

```
// webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './source/assets/javascripts/all.js'
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'] },
      { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname + './tmp/dist',
    filename: 'assets/javascripts/[name].bundle.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true,
      debug: false
    }),

    new ExtractTextPlugin('assets/stylesheets/[name].bundle.css'),

    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
      // In case you imported plugins individually, you must also require them here:
      Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
      Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
      Alert: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/alert",
      Carousel: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/carousel",
      Collapse: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/collapse",
      Modal: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/modal",
      Popover: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/popover",
      Scrollspy: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy",
      Tab: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/tab",
      Tooltip: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip",
    }),
  ]
};
```

My index.js:

```
// This is where it all goes :)
console.log("Hello world");
```

The console log outputs on the browser.

My `site.css.scss` file which is currently loading Bootstrap's styles:

```
@import "custom";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import "index";
```

Do I need to require or import jQuery elsewhere and not just in the webpack config?

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Not sure if I am able to help you. but If you do `console.log("jquery loaded", !!$ || !!jQuery);` in your `index.js` it prints false to the console?
AFAIK, using ProvidePlugin the way you are should work automatically

Comment: Yes, you need to import at least once `jQuery`, so that `webpack` will be able to load and package it (except if you use `ProvidePlugin`, that you did here) . What is your problem ? Do you have any error message ?